# Redirect from Origin Server to Akamai instance

Tags: php, drupal-7, cdn, akamai

Looking for some PHP help.  What I'd like to try (and find out if its feasible) is to redirect all traffic coming from origin back to the Akamai CDN url.  Obviously if I did this globally I would run into a loop.  So instead I've set up a header sent only by Akamai that would be ignored by my app if it was found.

What I'm looking for is the best method to accomplish this with PHP on my app.  Something along the lines of:

```
if (!$header_exists && $current_baseurl === origin.site.com {
    301 redirect to www.site.com version of same request URL
}
```

This would allow me to make sure no requests coming in from outside of Akamai are properly redirected.  Is this method sound? Does anyone currently has a code sample using a similar method?

Answer (score 4):

This is a complete wrong approach. What you need to do is implement site shield in Akamai. Site shield will have a set of Akamai IP's. If you allow only those IP's that should solve your problem. Akamai will make sure all the requests to Origin are sent from one of akamai site shield map. This way any request that is sent directly to origin will be denied and requests from Akamai will be allowed. Contact Akamai support to help you create and map site shield for your domains. No code changes are required for this.

Additionally you can allow your office IP if you want origin domain to be open for your testing purpose.